# JavaScript OnClick Method

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I was having trouble with the OnClick method I was learning while creating a game. Every time I enter the value and click the button, it is stuck in a loop, I tried document.write and it works using that, but than it opens a new page instead of showing up on screen.

I am new to the programming community, so any help would be nice.

```
<body>
  <p>Enter an integer between 1-100 here:
    <input id="number" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button onclick="onclickFunction()" type="button">Enter</button>
  </p>
  <p id="result"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onclickFunction() {
      var a = Math.random();
      var b = a * 100;
      var c = Math.ceil(b);
      var intNumber;
      var count = 0;
      var bool = false;

      do {
        do {
          intNumber = document.getElementById("number").value;

        }
        while (intNumber > 100 || intNumber < 0);
        if (intNumber > c) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too High " + "</br>";
          bool = false
        } else if (intNumber < c) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too Low " + "</br>";
          bool = false
        } else if (intNumber == c) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!" + "<br>" + " It took    you " + count + " tries";


          bool = true
        }
        count = count + 1
      } while (bool !== true);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Win!";

    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Updated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            // Declare all your functions first
            // These functions expect no parameters and return values.

                function onclickFunction() 
                {

                    var a = Math.random();
        var b = a * 100;
        var c = Math.floor(b);
                    // Input from text box.
                    var randomNumber = document.getElementById("number").value; 

                    // Output to paragraph.

                        if (randomNumber < c && randomNumber != c)
                        {
                              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too Low " + "</br>";
                        }
                        else if (randomNumber > c  && randomNumber != c )
                        {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too High" + "</br>";
                        }


                    else if (randomNumber == c)
                    {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Win!";
                    }

                    // Clear text box for further input.
                    document.getElementById("name").value = ""; 
                } 
        </script>
        <p>Enter an integer between 1-100 here: <input id="number" type="text" /></p>
        <p><button onclick="onclickFunction()" type="button">Enter</button></p>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
```

Comment: instead of do while, just use if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is always useful to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).
That way people who are reading your question can run your code immediately.

Let's break down the code

```
  var a = Math.random();
  var b = a * 100;
  var c = Math.ceil(b);
```

This can be done in a single line, to save variables.

```
  do
  {
  intNumber = document.getElementById("number").value; 

  }
  while (intNumber > 100 || intNumber < 0);
```

I'm not a big fan of using do/while loops this way, although it can come handy when you want to run the do code at least once, like now.

This loop keeps running when the number is bigger than 100, or smaller than 0. So if I pick an incorrect number that means my browser crashes.

```
if (intNumber>c){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too High " + "</br>"; 
  bool = false
   }else if (intNumber<c){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Too Low " + "</br>"; 
   bool = false
   }else if (intNumber == c){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!" + "<br>" + " It took    you " + count + " tries"; 


  bool = true
   }
```

First you are checking if the guess is bigger than the answer, than if it's smaller. That means that the last check if it's equal is unnecessary, since that is the only option left. You can just use an else here.

Also try to be consistent with your spacing and where you place your curly brackets.

```
do{
//Stuff
}
```

and

```
do
{
//Stuff
}
```

Are both valid ways to use brackets, but stick to one style or your code will get too confusing.

```
count = count + 1
```

A small oversight here is that the count starts at 0. So when you guess the number in a single try, it will say you have done it in 0 tries.

```
while (bool !== true);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Win!"; 

     }
```

All the previous code will be done until bool becomes true. The problem here is that if I entered a wrong number (or an invalid number). The program will keep running the if statement which requires a lot of computer power since it never stops. It is impossible to change your guess and the page crashes, because the browser is stuck in the while loop.

The simplest solution for this is to calculate if the new guess was correct when the player inputs a new number. So when `onClickFunction` is called again.
That way you never have to use a while loop. Although you have to calculate the random number somewhere else.

I hope that helped, if you have any question let me know!

Comment: I will let you know if I need help

Comment: Calculate if it's correct only once when the user presses the button. Return the feedback and then the user can fill in a different number and click the button again.

Comment: I tried, what you said, though If I call a new function each time it is wrong, it starts the whole thing over again, how can I fix this?

Comment: @ishdijcks I updated the code, can you please tell me what I did wrong, I don't understand

Comment: Start over, and don't use a while loop.

Comment: I did it like you said, I updated the code at the top, It's not stuck in a loop though, if I click the button once than it finishes, If I click it again, than it creates a new number

Comment: Yup, because the code that generates a new number is inside the function that you call each time, so aa new number is being generated every keypress. You want to make the random number a global variable that is calculated when the page loads.

Comment: Also think about this logic `randomNumber > c  && randomNumber != c `

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. It's so satisfying when something works, especially in the early days. @ishadijcks

Comment: No problem, keep on coding!